# Why are the results for 1 = NULL and 1 != NULL the same?

Tags: sql, database, null

The following

```
IF 1 = NULL 
    BEGIN
        SELECT  'A'
    END
ELSE 
    BEGIN
        SELECT  'B'
    END
```

Returns the result B as expected

Here's where things get really interesting

```
IF 1 != NULL 
    BEGIN
        SELECT  'A'
    END
ELSE 
    BEGIN
        SELECT  'B'
    END
```

Also returns B

Why is this the case?

Comment: You can't equal 'nothing'.

Comment: `NULL` is never equal to, not equal to, greater or less than anything.

Comment: Really? It can't be not equal?

Comment: You can't equal 'nothing'. Nor can you not equal nothing. Just like you can't add nothing or subtract nothing or multiply nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agree with what everyone else has already said. Simply commenting from another angle, if you try setting `ansi_nulls` to off, you may get what you expected:

```
set ansi_nulls off

if 1 = null
    select 'a'
else
    select 'b' -- Returned


if 1 != null
    select 'a' -- Returned
else
    select 'b'
```

More info from Books Online:

> When SET ANSI_NULLS is OFF, the Equals (=) and Not Equal To (<>)
>   comparison operators do not follow the ISO standard. A SELECT
>   statement that uses WHERE column_name = NULL returns the rows that
>   have null values in column_name. A SELECT statement that uses WHERE
>   column_name <> NULL returns the rows that have nonnull values in the
>   column. Also, a SELECT statement that uses WHERE column_name <>
>   XYZ_value returns all rows that are not XYZ_value and that are not
>   NULL.

That's `ansi_nulls off` explained. However, don't be tempted to simply switch it off because:

> In a future version of SQL Server, ANSI_NULLS will always be ON and
>   any applications that explicitly set the option to OFF will generate
>   an error. Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan
>   to modify applications that currently use this feature.

Follow the below recommendation instead:

> For a script to work as intended, regardless of the ANSI_NULLS
>   database option or the setting of SET ANSI_NULLS, use IS NULL and IS
>   NOT NULL in comparisons that might contain null values.

```
if 1 is null
    select 'a'
else
    select 'b' -- Returned


if 1 is not null
    select 'a' -- Returned
else
    select 'b'
```

Answer (score 7):

Neither `IF` statement is true.  `NULL` is neither equal to something nor not equal to something.  Something either `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL`.

Answer (score 2):

It is neither equal to nor not-equal to `NULL` because `NULL` is not a **thing** but, in fact, the absence of a thing.

ANSI SQL 1999 (not MSSQL yet, though) includes a method called `IS [NOT] DISTINCT FROM` which can be used on `NULL` with the results you might expect.

[How to rewrite IS DISTINCT FROM and IS NOT DISTINCT FROM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10416789/how-to-rewrite-is-distinct-from-and-is-not-distinct-from)

Here is an excellent post on `IS DISTINCT FROM` behavior and the confusing nature of `NULL` in general by Itzik Ben-Gan

http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/not-distinct

> The predicate can evaluate to TRUE, FALSE or UNKNOWN. The predicate evaluates to UNKNOWN whenever NULLs are involved.

Here is Erland Sommarskog wishing for it:

http://www.sommarskog.se/wishlist.html#isdistinctfrom

> SQL:1999 defines the operators IS DISTINCT FROM and IS NOT DISTINCT FROM which are the same as <> and = respectively, except that they also applies to NULL values.

(From Erland) here is a link on Connect for MVP Steve Kass requesting the feature:

http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/286422/add-language-and-optimizer-support-for-iso-distinct-predicate

> This is a common requirement, but coding this for many columns is both tedious and error-prone (especially because of AND/OR precedence issues). Changing the setting of ANSI_NULLS is not a solution, because it does not affect column-to-column comparisons, only column to variable comparisons. Setting ANSI_NULLS to off is also non-standard and not granular enough to apply to specific comparisons in a single query.

Answer (score 1):

You can't compare `NULL` = `NULL` - it has no value.

```
SELECT 1 
WHERE NULL = NULL
```

Does not return anything

When comparing `NULL` values use `IS` not `=`

```
SELECT 1
WHERE NULL IS NULL
```

Reuturns 1

**From MSDN:**

> To determine if an expression is NULL, use IS NULL or IS NOT NULL
>   rather than comparison operators (such as = or !=). Comparison
>   operators return UNKNOWN if either or both arguments are NULL.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933227

Answer (score 1):

It's simple. In ANSI terms, any expression (logical or arithmetical) involving NULL has unknown result:

```
(1 = NULL) IS UNKNOWN
(1 <> NULL) IS UNKNOWN
(1 + NULL) IS UNKNOWN
(1 * NULL) IS UNKNOWN
```

Therefore, in both cases you end up in the ELSE branch.

Try [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259229%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) link for more explanations.

Comment: From your link _...all comparisons against a null value evaluate to UNKNOWN_ will edit your response to correct.

Comment: @ShannonSeverance That sounds better. You can't query SELECT 1=NULL - this fails parsing. I'll remember your comment.

Comment: The vocabulary is confused. PL/SQL has a Boolean datatype. Booleans can take three values: `true`, `false` and `null`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess NULL is specified that it is, in a way, uncomparable by <,>,=,!= operators. Such comparison probably returns NULL. Then the `if(NULL)` processing is skipped.