# MYSQL - not equal joins not working properly

Tags: mysql

I'm having trouble getting a query to work properly.  I feel that this should be easy but for some reason I can't get it correct.

I have two tables joined by an ID field.  I'm trying to get all the records that are in t1 and don't show up in t2.

This works currently:

```
select * from at_templates a
left join at_vault b on a.id = b.template
where  b.at_id is null
```

BUT, I also want to put another condition in the query to limit the data to a subset and it is not working:

```
select * from at_templates a
left join at_vault b on a.id = b.template
where  b.at_id != 1
```

The second query comes up empty but I want the same results as the first, based upon the input of at_id.

Any ideas?

Comment: It's not clear to me what "the same results as the first, based upon the input of at_id" means.  You seem to be saying that you are want a query that will return a subset of the results your first query gets.  You cannot do that by adding an additional condition on b.at_id (because the current one is already as selective as can be) or by changing the current one (because then you won't get a subset).

Answer (score 1):

Your working example implies that the "first table" you want to see records from is `a` and the "second table" you want to use to *exclude* records is `b`. If you are *excluding* all records that exist in `b`, then you can't further limit the result set by any value like `b.at_id` because there *are* no values associated with `b` in your result set.

Additionally, if the condition `b.at_id is null` is true, the condition `b.at_id != 1` will never be true because [an inequality comparison with `null` will always return `null`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html). (The reason for this is that `null` is not a value; it is a placeholder indicating the *absence* of a value.)

If you want to get the same results from both queries, based on a comparison between some user input parameter and the field `b.at_id` (and noting that your second query currently returns an empty set), you might be able to use [MySQL's null-safe equality operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to) in the following way:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  at_templates AS a
    LEFT JOIN
  at_vault AS b ON a.id = b.template
WHERE NOT b.at_id <=> 1;
```

This is a MySQL extension, not a standard syntax; unfortunately the ANSI SQL standard syntax, `IS [NOT] DISTINCT FROM`, doesn't appear to be widely supported. Some alternate ways to rewrite this condition are discussed in [How to rewrite IS DISTINCT FROM and IS NOT DISTINCT FROM?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10416789/2359271).

Keep in mind that if in the future you have some values of `b.at_id` that are not 1, this query would return those rows as well, and not just the rows returned by your first query.