# Left outer join in BigQuery on multiple keys doesn't if one of them is null

Tags: google-bigquery

I ran into something odd with left outer joins on multiple keys in BigQuery. If one of the keys is `null` on right table it doesn't match and therefore it puts `null` in all the values for the right table.

If I've got 2 tables

```
   Table1              Table2
------------      ----------------
 k1 |k2  |v3      k1 |k2  | v4
------------      ----------------
 foo|boo |hey     foo|NULL| you
 bar|test|yo      bar|test| hi
 foo|NULL|hey
```

and I do the following join

```
SELECT t1.k1, t1.k2, t1.v3, t2.v4 FROM [Table1] t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN EACH [Table2] t2 
ON t1.k1=t2.k1 AND t1.k2=t2.k2
```

I get a result like this

```
t1_k1|t1_k2|t1_v3|t2_v4
-----------------------
foo  |boo  |hey  |NULL  --No match here so NULL in t2_v4 it's ok
bar  |test |hey  |hi    --It matches here on bar and test
foo  |NULL |hey  |NULL  --It doesn't match on foo NULL.
```

I would expect that the last row was

```
foo  |NULL |hey  |you
```

Is that the expected behaviour? With this I mean is no matches on `NULL`.

Is there any other way of producing the result I want?

Comment: Some other SQLs have "IS NOT DISTINCT FROM", but BigQuery doesn't have it. See more at, "How to rewrite IS DISTINCT FROM and IS NOT DISTINCT FROM?" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10416789/how-to-rewrite-is-distinct-from-and-is-not-distinct-from

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In SQL, `NULL` is not equal to anything--even itself.

[Gordon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31331371/1375400) has some reasonable suggestions, but note that BigQuery only supports join conditions that are conjunctions of equalities, which rules out use of `OR` or `IS NULL`.

Can you use a sentinel value other than null? For example, if you replace `NULL` with the empty string (or the string `"null"`, or something else that doesn't occur elsewhere in your data), the join will work as you expect. You can even do this on the fly by using a subquery, at minimal performance cost.

```
SELECT t1.k1, t1.k2, t1.v3, t2.v4
FROM
  (SELECT IFNULL(k1, "null") k1, IFNULL(k2, "null") k2 FROM [Table1]) t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN EACH
  (SELECT IFNULL(v3, "null") v3, IFNULL(v4, "null") v4 FROM [Table2]) t2
ON t1.k1 = t2.k1 AND t1.k2 = t2.k2
```

You can add an outer select to turn the string `"null"` back into a real `NULL`.

Obviously this only works if the string `"null"` doesn't occur elsewhere in your data.

Answer (score 3):

This is standard behavior.  One method to fix it is to make the `join` clause more complicated:

```
SELECT t1.k1, t1.k2, t1.v3, t2.v4
FROM [Table1] t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN EACH 
     [Table2] t2 
     ON (t1.k1 = t2.k1 OR (t1.k1 is null and t2.k1 is null)) AND
        (t1.k2 = t2.k2 OR (t1.k2 is null and t2.k2 is null))
```

This could have a bad impact on performance.  Some databases have a null-safe equality operation that can be used, but I don't think BigQuery supports that.

So, the best advice is to fix the data so `NULL` is not a valid key value.  Otherwise, you can use multiple joins.  If you only had one `join` key, it would look like

```
SELECT t1.k1, t1.k2, t1.v3, coalesce(t2.v4, t2null.v4)
FROM [Table1] t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN EACH 
     [Table2] t2 
     ON t1.k1 = t2.k1  LEFT OUTER JOIN EACH
     [Table2] t2null
     ON (t1.k1 is null and t2.k1 is null) ;
```

However, this is harder to put together for composite `join` keys.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today on Bigquery (standard SQL) and I solved it using CASE WHEN.

```
SELECT t1.k1, t1.k2, t1.v3, t2.v4 FROM [Table1] t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN EACH [Table2] t2 
ON t1.k1=t2.k1 
AND CASE WHEN(t1.k2 IS NULL THEN '1' ELSE t1.k2 END) = CASE WHEN(t2.k2 IS NULL THEN '1' ELSE t2.k2 END)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is just with how BigQuery handles null and not a problem with general SQL, so based on the same explanation from Gordon and Geremy this also should work,

```
SELECT t1.k1, t1.k2, t1.v3, t2.v4 FROM [Table1] t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN EACH [Table2] t2 
ON IFNULL(t1.k1,"null")=IFNULL(t2.k1,"null") 
   AND IFNULL(t1.k2,"null")=IFNULL(t2.k2, "null")
```

I had a similar problem and fixed it in the above manner.