# How to use case instead of IsNull

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the below query to be re-written without using the IsNull operator as I am using the encryption on those columns and IsNull isn't supported.

```
Case When Indicator = 'N' Then Null 
Else IsNull(c.email1, IsNull(E.email, ORG_Email)) End EmailAddress
```

Comment: If you have more than two things to compare and pick the first non-null, you can use [coalesce](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) instead of calling `isnull` multiple times. Not sure if that would help you here though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you would do it with a `case` statement:

```
Case 
    when Indicator = 'N' then Null 
    when c.email1 is not null then c.email1 
    when e.email is not null then e.email 
    else ORG_Email
end EmailAddress
```

However as others have pointed out, another option would be to use `coalesce` if that'll work for your needs.  Not sure why `isnull` isn't supported.

Comment: In the above condition what happens if the Indicator != 'N'  ?

Comment: @HadoopAddict -- this should be equivalent to your existing statement.  If indicator != 'N', then it checks to see if the `c.email1` field is not null.  If not, select that, if null, check the next -- basically think of this as `if else if`...

Comment: or in the above answer did you forget to use else at the end of each 'then' statement ?

Comment: @HadoopAddict -- when using `case`, you can have multiple `when then` clauses.  As I mentioned, think of it as `if, else if, else if, else`.  You can string as many as you need.

Comment: Great ! I really want to use Case statements to achieve the result. But How can I solve this part of problem. 
Can  I use any operator instead of LEN ? 

Len(IsNull(c.email1, IsNull(e.email, ORG_Email)) ) <> 0

Comment: @HadoopAddict -- not sure I'm following but that sounds like a different question.  Probably best to post a new question for such.

Comment: asked here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38744997/replacing-isnull-and-len-with-case-and-is-null

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest `coalesce()` for this purpose:

```
(Case When Indicator = 'N' Then Null
      Else coalesce(c.email1, E.email, ORG_Email)
 End) as EmailAddress
```

But I would phrase this without the `else`.  Assuming `Indicator` is never `NULL`:

```
(case when Indicator <> 'N' 
      then coalesce(c.email1, E.email, ORG_Email)
 end) as EmailAddress
```

Comment: If `Indicator` might be null, check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10416789/how-to-rewrite-is-distinct-from-and-is-not-distinct-from

Answer (score 0):

> I have the below query to be re-written without using the IsNull operator as I am using the encryption on those columns and IsNull isn't supported

I suppose you mean that columns `c.email1` and `E.email` are never null, but they sometimes contain encrypted strings that convey the absence of data in a manner similar to that ordinarily conveyed by a NULL.  For example, maybe the encrypted form of an empty string is used.  In that event, you can compare their values to the encrypted null-equivalent:

```
Case
  When Indicator = 'N' Then Null 
  when c.email1 != 'some-encrypted-string-equivalent-to-null' then c.email1
  when E.email != 'some-encrypted-string-equivalent-to-null' then E.email
  else ORG_Email
End EmailAddress
```

Of course, that assumes that there is a single null-equivalent string, at least on a per-column basis, which might not be the case.  If it isn't then the only options I see are

1. decrypt the e-mail values in the query (possibly via a user-defined function) and write the conditions based on the decrypted values, or
2. return both the encypted `c.email1` and `E.email` as separate columns, or null for both if `Indicator` is `'N'`, and select which one to use on the application side, after decryption.