# Replacing IsNull and LEN with Case and IS NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using always encrypted and couldn't use IsNull or LEN function. I want to use case and IS NULL or IS NOT NULL to achieve that.

Can someone let me know how to re-write the below logic using CASE and IS NULL/ IS NOT NULL?

```
Len(IsNull(c.email1, IsNull(e.email,ORG_Email))) <> 0
```

Update 2 :

```
case when email_indicator != 'N' and Len(IsNull(c.email1, IsNull(e.email,ORG_Email))) <> 0

Then 'E' else 'N' End
```

Answer (score 3):

I would write this as:

```
len(coalesce(c.email1, e.email, org_email)) <> 0
```

but you probably have the same problem.  So the answer to your question using `case` and `is null` is:

```
(case when c.email1 is null and e.email is null and org_email is null
      then 0   -- all are missing
      else 1
 end) = 1
```

I don't like `case` statements in the `where` clause, so the better answer is the simpler expression:

```
(c.email1 is not null or e.email is not null or org_email is not null)
```

This is really the right way to express the logic.

Comment: In your second answer, what if one of the emails is not null ?

Comment: I have added an update to the question. I am really trying to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want ?
If you want the email:

```
case when c.email1 is not null then c.email1 
     when e.email is not null then c.email
     else ORG_Email end
```

If all you want is to determine if an email exists:

```
case when c.email1 is not null then 1
     when e.email is not null then 1
     when ORG_Email is not null then 1 else 0 end
```

or combine the cases

```
case when c.email1 is not null Or e.email is not null Or
          ORG_Email is not null then 1 else 0 end
```

Comment: I have added an update to the question. I am really trying to achieve that