# SQL Server Compare to NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, null

I have a lot of comparisons that I need to make between a value and its previous value.

For Example: `ReceivedBy` and `PreviousReceivedBy`.

I started with:

```
WHERE ReceivedBy != PreviousReceivedBy
```

But if either value is null then this returns false, (when I really need it to be  true).  So I updated it to look like this:

```
WHERE ReceivedBy != PreviousReceivedBy
      OR (ReceivedBy IS NULL AND PreviousReceivedBy IS NOT NULL)
      OR (ReceivedBy IS NOT NULL AND PreviousReceivedBy IS NULL)
```

This works fine, but I have a large list of fields that need to be compared.  I would like to find a way to make this comparison with less code (without turning off `ANSI_NULLS`).

Obviously if there is no other way, then I will just put in all 3 lines for the comparison.

UPDATE:

As an example, here is what I am hoping for

```
ReceivedBy = 123  
PreviousReceivedBy = 123  
Result = FALSE  

ReceivedBy = 5  
PreviousReceivedBy = 123  
Result = TRUE  

ReceivedBy = NULL  
PreviousReceivedBy = 123  
Result = TRUE

ReceivedBy = 123  
PreviousReceivedBy = NULL  
Result = TRUE  

ReceivedBy = NULL  
PreviousReceivedBy = NULL  
Result = FALSE
```

Comment: How about `WHERE isnull(ReceivedBy,'ReceivedBy is null')') != isnull(PreviousReceivedBy,'PreviousReceivedBy is null')`...

Comment: In Hackerman's answer above, if both values are NULL, `isnull(ReceivedBy,'ReceivedBy is null')') != isnull(PreviousReceivedBy,'PreviousReceivedBy is null')` would be TRUE when it should be FALSE. (Could be fixed by replacing both literals with another, equal value.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I encountered the same problem with you when taking comparison with nullable value, `NULL` always returns `unknown` as far away of our desired only between `TRUE` or `FALSE`

I ended up with declare a Scalar-valued functions with these logics like [other SQL(s)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-comparison.html) dealing with null as

> Ordinary comparison operators yield null (signifying "unknown"), not
>   true or false, when either input is null. For example, 7 = NULL yields
>   null, as does 7 <> NULL. When this behavior is not suitable, use the
>   IS [ NOT ] DISTINCT FROM constructs:

```
a IS DISTINCT FROM b => a != b
a IS NOT DISTINCT FROM b => a == b
```

Which `a IS NOT DISTINCT FROM b` [could be rewritten](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25261909/3789481) as

```
(a IS NOT NULL AND b IS NOT NULL AND a=b) OR (a IS NULL AND b is NULL)
```

I use [sql_variant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/sql-variant-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) for these basic parameters: int, datetime, varchar,...

```
create function IsEqual(
    @a sql_variant,
    @b sql_variant
)
returns bit
as
begin
    return (CASE WHEN (@a IS NOT NULL AND @b IS NOT NULL AND @a=@b) OR (@a IS NULL AND @b is NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END);
end

create function IsNotEqual(
    @a sql_variant,
    @b sql_variant
)
returns bit
as
begin
    return 1-dbo.IsEqual(@a,@b);
end
```

To use

```
select dbo.IsEqual(null, null) Null_IsEqual_Null,
dbo.IsEqual(null, 1) Null_IsEqual_1,
dbo.IsEqual(1, null) _1_IsEqual_Null,
dbo.IsEqual(1, 1)  _1_IsEqual_1,
dbo.IsEqual(CAST('2017-08-25' AS datetime), null) Date_IsEqual_Null,
dbo.IsEqual(CAST('2017-08-25' AS datetime), CAST('2017-08-25' AS datetime)) Date_IsEqual_Date
```

[image: Result]

For your cases

```
select dbo.IsNotEqual(123,123) _123_IsNotEqual_123,
dbo.IsNotEqual(5,123) _5_IsNotEqual_123,
dbo.IsNotEqual(Null,123) Null_IsNotEqual_123,
dbo.IsNotEqual(123,Null) _123_IsNotEqual_Null,
dbo.IsNotEqual(Null,Null) Null_IsNotEqual_Null
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

If both columns are `varchar`s, I'd go with something like this:

```
coalesce(ReceivedBy, 'NULL') != coalesce(PreviousReceivedBy, 'NULL')
```

If they are integers, I'd put some values greatly below zero (to distinctly represent `null` value) instead of `'NULL'`.

From names of columns I assume it has to be wether string value or integer value :)

**UPDATE**

As @Siyual pointed out, replacement string should be "out of the realm of possibility", you should replace `'NULL'` above with some non-alphabetical character, as `'#'` :)

Comment: I would point out that the value could be literally anything, and the null check should be something outside of the realm of possibility.  I seem to remember a case with an airline company that did this exact thing, and then met someone whose legitimate family name was `Null`.  The airline company lost ;)

Comment: You can also use ISNULL instead of COALESCE (A bit shorter and easier to type :p)

Comment: If the expressions are of type `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` then it will result in "Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier." because those alternative strings cannot be converted to uids for comparison.

Answer (score 3):

Another method without munging the data would be to use `COALESCE`

```
Where ReceivedBy != PreviousReceivedBy
And Coalesce(ReceivedBy, PreviousReceivedBy) Is Not Null
```

`NULL` cannot equal anything, not even another `NULL`, so if any of the values are `NULL`, `ReceivedBy != PreviousReceivedBy` will evaluate as true.

Secondly, if both of the values are `NULL`, the `Coalesce(ReceivedBy, PreviousReceivedBy) Is Not Null` will evaluate as false, forcing those to be filtered.

If neither are `NULL`, the first condition would fail if they are equal.

Admittedly, it’s not saving too much code, but it is an improvement.

This can be easily grouped in parenthesis and copy/pasta’d for all remaining fields you need to check.

```
Where (ReceivedBy != PreviousReceivedBy And Coalesce(ReceivedBy, PreviousReceivedBy) Is Not Null)
And[Or] (Foo != Bar And Coalesce(Foo, Bar) Is Not Null)
...
```

Comment: This does not seem to work when the values are the same.

Comment: @Vaccano I wasn’t aware you needed that condition.  Are you only looking for things where they’re both not null, then?

Comment: My original statement was `WHERE ReceivedBy != PreviousReceivedBy` to catch only scenarios where they are different.  So I need it to evaluate to `FALSE` if the values are the same.  The first half will be FALSE, but if they are both a non-null value, then the second half will be TRUE.  FALSE OR TRUE = TRUE.  So my expression would then catch things that are the same, and I need them excluded.

Comment: See my updated question for the examples of what I am hoping for.

Comment: @Vaccano I see - updated the `OR` to an `AND` for that logic.  This would require one of the values to be non-null and for them not to be equal.  I can’t test this at the moment, but this should be correct - please let me know if it isn’t.  `NULL` cannot equal anything, so the first check would pass if one is null, and two `NULL` values would be filtered out by the second.  If neither are `NULL`, the comparison will function as normal.

Comment: I think there is a flaw here. I recently learned that a comparison to null always equals UNKNOWN. which cannot be "NOT"ed to TRUE. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50919888/16241  I think I will have to just go with my expanded logic. **Thank you for taking the time to look into this.**

Answer (score 3):

```
WHERE ISNULL(ReceivedBy, -1) != ISNULL(PreviousReceivedBy, -1)
```

assuming the columns never have negative values

Answer (score 3):

> if either value is null then this returns false

It actually returns "unknown" rather than "false" (SQL uses three valued logic). But in a `WHERE` clause the combined predicates must evaluate to "true" for the row to be returned so the effect here is much the same.

From SQL Server 2022 [you can use](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/is-distinct-from-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

```
WHERE  ReceivedBy IS DISTINCT FROM PreviousReceivedBy
```

Comment: This is a game changer. What a pity I'm running an older version of SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @phantom_not_null int = -1

DECLARE @Tests TABLE (Expected int, Actual int)

INSERT @Tests VALUES (NULL, NULL), (NULL, 0), (0, NULL), (0, 0), (0, 1)

SELECT * FROM @Tests 
WHERE ISNULL(Expected, @phantom_not_null) != ISNULL(Actual, @phantom_not_null)
```

[image: Results here]

Answer (score -1):

`(NULLIF(@a, @b) IS NOT NULL) OR (NULLIF(@b, @a) IS NOT NULL)` means `"@a != @b` even if one of them or both are null.

Comment: You can use backticks (`) to highlight inline code. This will make it easier to understand the answer

Comment: This does _not_ work, since `declare @a int = null, @b int = 123; select nullif(@a, @b);` returns NULL (false) even though @a != @b (it should be true).

Comment: Try this: `(NULLIF(@a, @b) IS NOT NULL) OR (NULLIF(@b, @a) IS NOT NULL)`