# Confusing null compares combined with NOT

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, null

I realize that comparing `NULL` to any other value (including `NULL`) will always result in false.

```
DECLARE @IsSet bit = NULL;

SELECT IIF(@IsSet = 1, 'true', 'false')
SELECT IIF(@IsSet != 1, 'true', 'false')
```

This outputs:

```
false
false
```

But this is part that confuses me:

```
SELECT IIF(NOT(@IsSet = 1), 'true', 'false')
SELECT IIF(NOT(@IsSet != 1), 'true', 'false')
```

This also outputs:

```
false
false
```

I would expect that the `NOT` would have flipped the value to TRUE.  (Which it does if `@IsSet` is set to 0 for the first expression)

It seems that the compare to the null value has some power over the boolean logic outside the parenthesis.

But the null compare is not all powerful over boolean logic:

```
SELECT IIF((@IsSet = 1) OR (1=1), 'true', 'false')
SELECT IIF((@IsSet != 1) OR (1=1), 'true', 'false')
```

This returns:

```
true
true
```

I don't understand what is happening here, but I assume that this is done on purpose.  But I don't know why.

Can someone explain why `NOT(NULL!=1)` does not equal true.

Comment: A comparison with `NULL` results in `UNKNOWN` rather than `TRUE` or `FALSE`. `NOT UNKNOWN` also results in `UNKNOWN`, which is neither `TRUE` nor `FALSE`. One cannot "flip" `UNKNOWN` to a Boolean value.

Comment: @DanGuzman - This makes sense.   With this additional information, I was able to google it and found this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/null-and-unknown-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017   Some limited `and` and `or` actions are allowed with UNKNOWN, but it is effectively nothing.  **Please consider posting as an answer.**

Comment: Rule of thumb: never, ever, ever compare anything to NULL.  The answer will never be what you expect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A comparison with `NULL` results in `UNKNOWN` rather than `TRUE` or `FALSE`. `NOT UNKNOWN` also results in `UNKNOWN`, which is neither `TRUE` nor `FALSE`. One cannot "flip" `UNKNOWN` to a Boolean value using `NOT`.

This 3-way logic requires one to use [`IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL`](http://IS%20NULL%20or%20IS%20NOT%20NULL) to test for NULL values rather than traditional Boolean logic.

Comment: Just to add this: In most cases it is up to the developer (specific business rules) to decide if a `NULL` in a given context is taken as `true` or `false`. In the given case I'd tend to use `IIF(ISNULL(@IsSet,0)=1,'true','false')`. This will set a `0` in the place of the `NULL` *before* the comparison takes place.

Answer (score 1):

The way you are using NOT is not correct. You'll get error, If you only execute the NOT condition as follows:

```
SELECT NOT(@IsSet = 1)
```

When you enclose your incorrect usage of NOT condition inside IIF condition, SQL server won't show you the error, However the statement will be evaluated to false output.

If you want to explicitly check for NULL value, then following practice can be adopted.

```
SELECT IIF(@IsSet IS NULL, 'true', 'false')
```

Lastly, the following condition is returning 'true' in output, because one of the OR condition (1==1) is always evaluating to 'true', hence the overall output of the IIF statement is true.

```
SELECT IIF((@IsSet = 1) OR (1=1), 'true', 'false')
SELECT IIF((@IsSet != 1) OR (1=1), 'true', 'false')
```