# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'x' to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server, null, isnull

I have a `WHERE` condition which works for the type STRING but fails for an of type INT

```
 isnull(emp.name, 'x') <> isnull(mst.name, 'x')  -- works
```

But this condition below throws an error:

```
 isnull(emp.age, 'x') <> isnull(mst.age, 'x')   -- fails
```

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'x' to data type int.

where name is a STRING and age is of INT type.

How to rectify this?

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `isnull()` for this purpose -- or even `coalesce()`.  Just expand out the logic:

```
where (emp.age = mst.age or emp.age is null and mst.age is null)
```

You *could* put in a fake value and use `coalesce()`, but the types need to be consistent.  However, I think you are better off with explicit logic that does what you want and works for all data types.

Answer (score 2):

`ISNULL` will attempt to convert the datatype of second parameter to that of first parameter. The string `x` cannot be converted to int (assuming age is int). Use an integer value that, ideally, does not exist in your data:

```
isnull(emp.age, -1) <> isnull(mst.age, -1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that in your code, `'x'` will effectively be considered the same as `NULL`, which is unlikely to be what you want.  Fixing the error you get for `age` will not correct that problem.

Consider instead using the operator `IS DISTINCT FROM`, which is similar to `<>` but considers `NULL` as a "known value" (`NULL IS DISTINCT FROM NULL = FALSE` for example).

```
emp.name IS DISTINCT FROM mst.name
emp.age IS DISTINCT FROM mst.age
```

If your database engine does not support `IS DISTINCT FROM` then this related question will be helpful: [How to rewrite IS DISTINCT FROM and IS NOT DISTINCT FROM?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10416789/501250)

Comment: OP is using `<>`. You need a much longer logic.