# What is IS DISTINCT FROM doing?

Tags: postgresql

I am not very familiar with SQL and I am having trouble understanding what this query means. I think I understand most of it but I am confused what the IS DISTINCT is doing and why it needs to be include.

```
UPDATE t1
SET pop_count1=sub.pop_count1
FROM
  (SELECT state,
          count(*) AS pop_count1
   FROM t2
   WHERE stime < 3600
     AND stime + length > 0
   GROUP BY state) sub
WHERE t1.state=sub.state
  AND t1.pop_count1 IS DISTINCT FROM sub.pop_count1;
```

Comment: `t1.pop_count1 IS DISTINCT FROM sub.pop_count1` "is distict from": three words form one operator. The operator is `<>`, but it treats NULLs as if it were values. So: `NULL IS NOT DISTINCT FROM NULL` is true.

Comment: But if I am setting  `pop_count1=sub.pop_count1` shouldn't those always be the same

Comment: The operator is `IS DISTINCT FROM` and it's documented in [the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparison.html#FUNCTIONS-COMPARISON-PRED-TABLE)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I am still confused if it means 'not equal, treating null like an ordinary value' why would the sql check if pop_count1=sub.pop_count1 when the first part of the sql is setting `pop_count1=sub.pop_count1`? Am I missing something?

Comment: It only does the UPDATE if the values are different

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to rewrite IS DISTINCT FROM and IS NOT DISTINCT FROM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10416789/how-to-rewrite-is-distinct-from-and-is-not-distinct-from)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name so if t1.pop_count1 were NULL and sub.pop_count1 were some value, then it would do the update, correct?

Comment: The statement is declining to do the update when the update would be degenerate (updating the value to same thing it already is).  It is a performance optimization.

Answer (score 0):

`IS DISTINCT FROM` is an operator that is defined like this:

```
a IS DISTINCT FROM b
```

is the same as

```
a <> b OR (a IS NULL OR b IS NULL) AND NOT (a IS NULL AND b IS NULL)
```

So it is like the inequality operator `<>`, except that NULL is treated like a normal value unless the new value is different from the old one.

The purpose of the clause in the update statement is to not perform the update unless