# In Postgres, field != 'N' fails to include NULL value

Tags: postgresql, sql-null

We have a case in Postgres where

`where p.is_ready_for_submission != 'N'`

is failing to include NULL as a satisfying value for this condition. The column `is_ready_for_submission` can be `NULL`, `Y`, `N`. The purpose of the statement above is to include `NULL` and `Y`. But the NULLs are not included (they were in Oracle).

The only way to achieve this was to re-write as

```
(p.is_ready_for_submission is null or p.is_ready_for_submission = 'Y')
```

Is this special to Postgres? Note: this happens with both `!=` and `<>`.

Comment: I would be surprised if this was different in Oracle. Maybe try the standard `<>` instead of `!=`?

Comment: Correct, if the where condition is null in postgresql that counts as not satisfied. I'd be surprised if this was unique to postgresql (wouldn't the opposite be more surprising to a beginner?), but I haven't done a survey.

Comment: I tried both `!=` and `<>`.

Comment: I think sqlite *did* do a survey of null handling to help choose how they handled nulls in various situations, and included it in their documentation; you might want to look there.

Comment: "*But the NULLs are not included (they were in Oracle)*" - most certainly **not**. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=89cebaf88f34b825401afd974511e24c

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, this isn't specific to Postgres, it's the same in Oracle ([online example a](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=81606c3939c19637f0d50d7e78745e94), [online example b](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=81606c3939c19637f0d50d7e78745e94)). A `!=` or `<>` expression where one of the operands is `NULL` will evaluate to `NULL`, and this will be considered falsy in the `WHERE` clause.

To include `NULL` values in your results, you can use the SQL-1999 standard

```
p.is_ready_for_submission IS DISTINCT FROM 'n'
```

which [will not propagate `NULL` values](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparison.html#FUNCTIONS-COMPARISON-PRED-TABLE) but consider them as distinct values.

Unfortunately, [it's not supported in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10416789/1048572), [various alternatives](https://modern-sql.com/feature/is-distinct-from) exist (like the one in your question).

Answer (score 2):

It's universal and a fundamental premise of SQL: Any evaluation of a `null` results in `null`, which is not `true`.

But there's a universal workaround for a simplification:

```
where coalesce(p.is_ready_for_submission, 'N') != 'Y')
```

or possibly more clearly expressed:

```
where coalesce(p.is_ready_for_submission, 'Y') == 'Y')
```

The `coalesce()` function, which is part of the SQL standard, returns the first non-null parameter.

Certain databases have specific support:

###### MySQL

MySQL has the "null safe" equality operator `<=>`:

```
where not p.is_ready_for_submission <=> 'N'
```

See [live demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2bf6da/2).

###### Postgres

Postgres has the "null safe" `is distinct from` syntax:

```
where p.is_ready_for_submission is distinct from 'N'
```

See [live demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/2bf6da/1).