# How can I compare multiple fields/columns in Oracle with those fields/columns in the previous record

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to find duplicates in the Oracle table, but only those duplicates that are back to back, next to one another. For that I am using the following query

```
with a as
(
select  some_id, column1,  column2, column3, column4, column5, column6 
,lag(some_id) over (ORDER BY some_id) as prev_some_id
,lag(column1) over (ORDER BY some_id) as prev_column1
,lag(column2) over (ORDER BY some_id) as prev_column2
,lag(column3) over (ORDER BY some_id) as prev_column3
,lag(column4) over (ORDER BY some_id) as prev_column4
,lag(column5) over (ORDER BY some_id) as prev_column5
,lag(column6) over (ORDER BY some_id) as prev_column6

from   SOME_TABLE 
)
select * from a 
where some_id = prev_some_id
and column1 = prev_column1
and column2 = prev_column2
and column3 = prev_column3
and column4 = prev_column4
and column5 = prev_column5
```

However, for some reason, this query doesn't return duplicates. Can you please let me know what I am doing wrong?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I guess, some_id=prev_some_id looks suspicious (some_id is key ?) and columnX can contain NULL-values, but your code is not ready for it (may be NVL can solve this)

Comment: Please provide sample data, an example of the desired output, and the query you have attempted. Also, please explain what qualifies as duplicated data.

Comment: Unlike a spreadsheet, SQL has no inherent row order. There is no concept of "back to back" unless you give one with an `order by`. There's no point in finding "adjacent" duplicates.

Comment: @JasonSeekWell I did provide a query. Duplicate data is the data that identical for every field listed in the query in the previous row

Comment: @James What do you mean by previous row? Which row should be considered as previous row as Oracle table is unordered dataset. You need to provide some column based on which next/previous row can be identified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what worked for me

```
WITH  grid AS
    (  Select   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order By some_id, column1,  column2, column3, column4, column5, column6 ) "RN",
                 some_id, column1,  column2, column3, column4, column5, column6,
                  -9999 as prev_some_id, '<>' as prev_column1, '<>' as prev_column2, '<>' as prev_column3, -99 as prev_column4, -99 as prev_column5, -99 as prev_column6
        From       SOME_TABLE
        Order By some_id, column1,  column2, column3, column4, column5, column6 
    ),
    
sortedgrid as
(
    
Select  *
From    ( Select    RN, 
                 some_id, column1,  column2, column3, column4, column5, column6,
                    Nvl(LAG(some_id) Over(Order By RN), -999999) as prev_some_id,
                    Nvl(LAG(column1) Over(Order By RN), '**//**//')  as prev_column1,
                    Nvl(LAG(column2) Over(Order By RN), '**//**//') as prev_column2,
                    Nvl(LAG(column3) Over(Order By RN), '**//**//') as prev_column3,
                    Nvl(LAG(column4) Over(Order By RN), -999999)  as prev_column4,
                    Nvl(LAG(column5) Over(Order By RN), -999999)  as prev_column5,
                    Nvl(LAG(column6) Over(Order By RN), -999999) as prev_column6
          From      grid
          Order By  RN
        )

)

select * from sortedgrid

Where   some_id = prev_some_id And
        column1 = prev_column1 And
        column2 = prev_column2 And
        column3 = prev_column3 And
        column4 = prev_column4 And
        column5 = prev_column5 And
        column6 = prev_column6
```

Answer (score 1):

One option to do  it is to assign imposible values for null columns using Nvl() function. You should know the datatypes of columns for this to work. Here is an example...

```sql
WITH    --  S a m p l e    D a t a :
    tbl ( A_NUMBER, A_VARCHAR, A_DATE ) AS
        ( Select 1, 'text 1', DATE '2023-01-01' From Dual Union All 
          Select 3, 'text 3', DATE '2023-03-03' From Dual Union All
          Select null, null, DATE '2023-02-02' From Dual Union All 
          Select 2, 'text 2', null From Dual Union All 
          Select 3, 'text 3', DATE '2023-03-03' From Dual Union All
          Select 1, 'text 1', DATE '2023-01-01' From Dual Union All 
          Select 2, 'text 2', DATE '2023-02-02' From Dual 
        ),
```

Create CTE (grid) with additional columns containing values that don't exist in your table and add row number ordered by all your original columns

```sql
  grid AS
    (  Select   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order By A_NUMBER, A_VARCHAR, A_DATE) "RN",
                  A_NUMBER, A_VARCHAR, A_DATE,
                 -999999 "PREV_NUMBER", '**//**//' "PREV_VARCHAR", DATE '2062-10-11' "PREV_DATE"
        From       tbl
        Order By A_NUMBER, A_VARCHAR, A_DATE
    )
```

Now you can use LAG() analytic function with NVL() giving same imposible values as in grid cte instead of null

```sql
Select  *
From    ( Select    RN, 
                    A_NUMBER, A_VARCHAR, A_DATE,
                    Nvl(LAG(A_NUMBER) Over(Order By RN), -999999) "PREV_NUMBER",
                    Nvl(LAG(A_VARCHAR) Over(Order By RN), '**//**//') "PREV_VARCHAR",
                    Nvl(LAG(A_DATE) Over(Order By RN), DATE '2062-10-11') "PREV_DATE"
          From      grid
          Order By  RN
        )
Where   A_NUMBER = PREV_NUMBER And
        A_VARCHAR = PREV_VARCHAR And
        A_DATE = PREV_DATE
```

```sql
/*    R e s u l t :
        RN   A_NUMBER A_VARCHAR A_DATE   PREV_NUMBER PREV_VARCHAR PREV_DAT
---------- ---------- --------- -------- ----------- ----------- --------
         2          1 text 1    01.01.23           1 text 1      01.01.23   
         6          3 text 3    03.03.23           3 text 3      03.03.23   */
```

grid cte could be used with [MODEL clause](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/10g/r2/prod/bidw/sqlmodel/sqlmodel_otn.htm) (spreadsheet like processing in Oracle - fast and reliable) instead of LAG() analyitic function and result is the same as above...

```sql
SELECT  *
FROM (  Select  *
        From    ( Select    RN, 
                            A_NUMBER, A_VARCHAR, A_DATE,
                            PREV_NUMBER, PREV_VARCHAR, PREV_DATE
                  From      grid
                  Order By  RN
                )
            MODEL     Dimension By (RN)
                      Measures (A_NUMBER, A_VARCHAR, A_DATE, PREV_NUMBER, PREV_VARCHAR, PREV_DATE)
            RULES  (  PREV_NUMBER[ANY] = Nvl(A_NUMBER[CV() - 1], -999999), 
                      PREV_VARCHAR[ANY] = Nvl(A_VARCHAR[CV() - 1], '**//**//'), 
                      PREV_DATE[ANY] = Nvl(A_DATE[CV() - 1], DATE '2062-10-11')
                   ) 
      )
WHERE   A_NUMBER = PREV_NUMBER And
        A_VARCHAR = PREV_VARCHAR And
        A_DATE = PREV_DATE
```

Answer (score 0):

There's two issues with your query.

### Null never compares with anything, not even null.

In SQL, ["Null" means "unknown value" or "has no value"](https://learnsql.com/blog/null-comparison-operators/). It is not equal to, less than, nor greater than anything, not even false. All comparisons with null are false.

For example, your query would value to match these.

```
insert into some_table
  (2, null, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7),
  (2, null, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7);
```

Use [`is not distinct from`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/is-distinct-from-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) when you want to compare values which might be null.

```
select * from a 
where some_id is not distinct from prev_some_id
  and column1 is not distinct from prev_column1
  and column2 is not distinct from prev_column2
  and column3 is not distinct from prev_column3
  and column4 is not distinct from prev_column4
  and column5 is not distinct from prev_column5
```

If your database hasn't implemented `is not distinct from`, [here's how to emulate it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10416789/how-to-rewrite-is-distinct-from-and-is-not-distinct-from-in-sql-server-20008r2).

### SQL has no concept of adjacent rows.

Unlike a spreadsheet, there is no idea of "back to back" rows in SQL. SQL has no implied default order. There is only the ordering you give. Though it will *probably* use the order you inserted them, there is no guarantee, and there's many ways the stored row order can change.

Because you're ordering only by `some_id` the exact order of the rows with matching `some_id`s is left up to the database. That means the "previous" row can be anything. For example...

```
insert into some_table values
  (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
  (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
  (1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

That will [probably] match.

```
insert into some_table values
  (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7),
  (1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
  (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7);
```

That will [probably] not.

To make the query not depend on which way the wind is blowing in the database server, you must specify the order for all the columns you're comparing with. `(order by some_id, column1, column2, column3, column4, column5, column6)`.

Oracle 21c added support for `window` which we can use to define the window once.

```
select
  some_id, column1,  column2, column3, column4, column5, column6 
  ,lag(some_id) over previous as prev_some_id
  ,lag(column1) over previous as prev_column1
  ,lag(column2) over previous as prev_column2
  ,lag(column3) over previous as prev_column3
  ,lag(column4) over previous as prev_column4
  ,lag(column5) over previous as prev_column5
  ,lag(column6) over previous as prev_column6
from some_table
window previous as (
  order by some_id, column1, column2, column3, column4, column5, column6
)
```

At which point the idea of "adjacent" rows becomes moot, we defined it ourselves. Its simpler to drop the illusion of adjacency and look for duplicate rows anywhere in the table.

```
select some_id, column1, column2, column3, column4, column5, column6
from some_table
group by some_id, column1, column2, column3, column4, column5, column6
having count(*) > 1
```

[Demonstration](https://dbfiddle.uk/Xlv9W7wS).

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback. Just tried you syntax and received ORA-30484: missing window specification for this function error

Is there something that needs to be adjusted?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This question is tagged for Oracle but the `is not distinct from` is a recent addition to the SQL Server syntax.  It won't work in Oracle.  Neither will the `window previous as` syntax.  This is an excellent answer for SQL Server though!

Comment: @James It's possible your version of Oracle has not implemented `window` (added in 21c) and Oracle still has not implemented [`is not distinct from`](https://modern-sql.com/caniuse/is-not-distinct-from). I added a link to how to emulate `is not distinct from`.